# Heroku SSL Endpoint with purchased certificate does not seem to work

Tags: ssl, heroku

I have purchased an SSL certificate and installed it to my Heroku app.

However when I try to access my site via https, Chrome reports that:

> The identity of this website has not been verified.  • Server's
>   certificate does not match the URL.

Other browsers report a similar message.

Inspecting the certificate information in Chrome shows that my site is still using Heroku's certificate, issued by Digicert (instead of my own CA).

Any ideas as to what I could be missing?

Answer (score 15):

The problem had to do with an incorrectly set DNS record.

As per the documentation (...), once the certificates are uploaded to Heroku, do:

> heroku certs

This provides you the correct end point for the SSL enabled domain. This is a domain that looks like "tokyo-2121.herokussl.com".

Next, go to your DNS service provider and update/add the CNAMe record for the SSL enabled domain to point to "tokyo-2121.herokussl.com".

Comment: Somewhat confusingly, both SSL and nonSSL traffic should now be sent to the SSL endpoint. Which means that any CNAME's like app-instance-name.herokuapp.com should be removed as they are not needed. You do NOT need separate DNS entries for SSL and non-ssl traffic.

Comment: I modified my @ and www CNAME record to match the SSL endpoint in heroku certs but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: See in particular the Heroku docs at https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#subdomain. This fix worked for us. We have one DNS CNAME entry for *.example.com pointing to our SSL endpoint domain (which you can find via `heroku certs`), and after DNS propagation Chrome and Firefox started accepting the certificates.

Comment: Topher Hunt:  Your solution worked for me and helped me solve a 3+ hr bug.  Thank you!!!