# Added RapidSSL certificate for Heroku with DNS through Badger, but it's still "SSL mismatching" when browsed

Tags: ssl, heroku, openssl

Yesterday, I added a RapidSSL certificate, but going to supplybetter.com still gives an SSL mismatch warning, and the heroku certificate rather than mine is being presented. I'd like to get this working and get rid of the warning as soon as possible.

To get the certificate, I followed the instructions in [this tutorial](http://blog.pardner.com/2011/04/adding-ssl-to-an-app-hosted-at-heroku/), with the exception that there was no analogue to "../ssldir/myapp_mydomain_com_chain.key" in step 16, so I used the _chain-less .key file, the only one I had. My PEM is composed of my CRT followed by the intermediate CRT, with spacing / newlines correct after checking.

My DNS is through Badger.com, which interacts with Heroku; current records shown below. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650890/heroku-ssl-endpoint-with-purchased-certificate-does-not-seem-to-work) recommends adding a cname that I don't have, but there's no way for Badger to do that without uninstalling the Heroku plugin; it only allows one input, a "_______.herokuapp.com" address, and does the rest.

[image: Current domains]

Results of heroku certs and ssl

```
matt$ heroku certs
Endpoint                  Common Name(s)                          Expires               Trusted
------------------------  --------------------------------------  --------------------  -------
osaka-8681.herokussl.com  www.supplybetter.com, supplybetter.com  2014-03-09 23:27 UTC  True
matt$ heroku ssl
supplybetter.com has no certificate
www.supplybetter.com has no certificate
```

This question has been submitted to Badger and Heroku support; if there's not an accepted answer, I don't yet have a solution. Thank you for your help!

--

```
Heroku support:
```

"Hey,

So the tutorial you are following was for our legacy feature ssl:hostname which has been removed in place of ssl:endpoint. Running heroku certs, I see that your cert has been added properly. However, there is one final step, you need to point your CNAME to your ssl:endpoint osaka-8681.herokussl.com

Once you do that, just wait for the DNS to propagate and you should be good to go."

Issue now is that badger doesn't have a way I see of adding non-subdomain cnames, and their heroku app only takes things in ____.herokuapp.com format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS does not support CNAME records for the domain apex ("non-subdomain"). [Heroku docs recommend not using the apex domain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/avoiding-naked-domains-dns-arecords). You DNS provider may provide a redirect-function from domain.com to www.domain.com that you can take advantage of.

DNSimple has a feature that let's you use the apex on Heroku, but you'd have to switch away from badger: http://support.dnsimple.com/questions/32831-How-do-I-point-my-domain-apex-to-Heroku

Answer (score 0):

Badger support manually implemented the 3 A records that I needed, plus the correct CNAME to point to osaka.herokussl.com. My major mistake was that when faced with Badger's format to enter CNAMEs, _.domain.com, I didn't realize www would work. It's now propigated and working well.

Learned:

- As of 3/8/13, Badger's Heroku plugin can't support custom domains, but they're possible to add manually
- Badger support is very responsive